# What is the role of tbl() in a sparklyr query?

Tags: r, apache-spark, tidyverse, sparklyr

Let's say I have a query (character string) stored in an R object named `my_query`. I want to execute this query within my Spark context. I register some tables in my Spark context first.

```
my_table <- sparklyr::spark_read_orc(
  sc,
  name = "my_table",
  path = "wasbs://my_table",
  memory = FALSE
)
```

Now I execute my query.

```
my_query %>%
  dplyr::sql() %>%
  dplyr::tbl(sc, .) %>%
  sparklyr::spark_write_orc(path = "result_path", mode = "overwrite")
```

What exactly is the role of the `tbl()` function here? Does the `tbl()` function here bring the data into Spark memory? i.e. is the query still lazily evaluated? Does this depend on the type of query? For example I imagine that simple `SELECT` and `WHERE` statements don't require data to be brought into memory but if you are creating new columns in some form of `dplyr::mutate()` (or equivalent SQL code), it would need to bring that into memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is the role of the `tbl()` function here

It is generic method used to fetch table from external source.

Since `sparklyr` behaves effectively like a database connection it will follow the standard `dbplyr` path, by invoking `dblyr::tbl_sql`, which main responsibility is to prepare data structure representing the (lazy) data source, and resolve the schema, by invoking corresponding `db_query_fields` implementation.

The last part is pretty much the only Spark-specific component, which at the moment is implemented [as show below](https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/blob/72e7a3c715de154a6b19f38ad0f95529f3f8a66f/R/dplyr_spark_connection.R#L187-L205)

```
#' @export
#' @importFrom dplyr db_query_fields
#' @importFrom dplyr sql_select
#' @importFrom dplyr sql_subquery
#' @keywords internal
db_query_fields.spark_connection <- function(con, sql, ...) {
  sqlFields <- sql_select(
    con,
    sql("*"),
    sql_subquery(con, sql),
    where = sql("0 = 1")
  )


  hive_context(con) %>%
    invoke("sql", as.character(sqlFields)) %>%
    invoke("schema") %>%
    invoke("fieldNames") %>%
    as.character()
}
```

As you see there is not much going on here, and alone there is not much to worry about here.

As of arbitrary case it is impossible to provide a single answer. `sparklyr` design choices of being eagerish (by showing user the partial output) as well as eager caching used all over the package, can have unexpected implications.

Additionally Spark SQL is not strictly eager, and different types of operations might by itself result in partial evaluation.

However using `tbl` here, doesn't make your code any worse than using `my_table` directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes a lot of sense.